# ES6 opposite of includes logic

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

in order to remove objects from array i can find the objects i want to remove using the following piece of code:

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item => this.multipleSelectedIds.includes(item.id))
```

but than what happens is i assign to the `this.data` array all the objects i actually want to remove from it. 
what will be an ES6 best practice logic to implement sort of "exclude", so what i get is all the objects which there id's are not in the `this.multipleSelectedIds` instead of what i have now which is exactly the opposite?

Comment: use the `NOT` operator `!`

Comment: `!this.multipleSelectedIds.includes...`?

Comment: Not every cool JS feature is ES6. It's ES2016.

Answer (score 14):

Simply use `!`, the NOT operator:

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item => !this.multipleSelectedIds.includes(item.id))
// ----------------------------------^
```

---

Since the above makes multiple passes through `multipleSelectedIds` (one for every entry in `this.data`), if these are ***very*** large arrays, it may be worth making a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or object of the `id` values it contains and then using the set/object instead, e.g.:

Using a `Set`:

```
const ids = new Set();
this.multipleSelectedIds.forEach(id => {
    ids.add(id);
});
this.data = this.data.filter(item => !ids.has(item.id))
```

Using an object:

```
const ids = Object.create(null);
this.multipleSelectedIds.forEach(id => {
    ids[id] = true;
});
this.data = this.data.filter(item => !ids[item.id])
```

...but you'd have to be dealing with very large arrays for the overhead to be worthwhile.

Comment: @AndrewK - Thanks! Fixed. Feel free to directly edit in corrections like that where it's clear (as in this case) that it doesn't conflict with the author's intent. (Particularly on a community wiki answer.) But commenting if you're at all unsure is great. Thanks again!